# Angular - How to get URL when using Hash-Strategy?

Tags: javascript, angular, url, angular-router

In my Angular Route, I define that I'm using Hash strategy:

```
// app-routing-module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true
    })
  ],
//...
```

When I want to test the current Router url, I run this code:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
// ..

constructor(private _router: Router) {}

getUrl() {
  return this._router.url; // always return '/'
}
```

The `this._router.url` is always equal to '/'. However, if I test `window.location.href`, I'm getting a different value (the real full url).

How do I get the current router-url (in the Angular way, not via window object) while using **Hash Strategy**?

Comment: Why router? Why not route snapshot?
Not different angular api using with and without hash strategy.

Comment: @Numichi - could you post an Answer where you explain how to get the router url with snapshot route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PlatformLocation` class like this:

```
import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private pLocation: PlatformLocation) { }

getUrl() {
  return (pLocation as any).location.href;
}
```

The reason I coded `(pLocation as any)` is that `location` is not showing it typescript intellisense, as you can see it is not showing in [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation), but it is there and you can use it.

[SIMPLE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-angular-routing-get-url)

Comment: Great. What I was needed was actually `platformLocation.hash` which was equal to `#/page1` (the part after the '#' of the url)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) to get URL as Numichi mentioned

Comment: Could you add an example of use. How do I get the URL from `ActivatedRoute`